# How can I get audio stream URL or content in Telegram?

Tags: android, audio, broadcastreceiver, telegram

I'm trying to get audio streaming in Telegram. I can get event when it starts to play with an intent `org.telegram.android.musicplayer.play`. But the intent which is returned has nothing useful.

Can anyone help me to know how can I get file path Telegram stores audio in phone when streaming or get URL of streaming content pragmatically?

Or is it possible to save streaming content directly into a byte array when telegram streams??

Answer (score 0):

**Send your audio/media content to https://t.me/uploadgrammebot. It will respond you with a specific link, where was the content uploaded. Add ?raw to that link to get raw(direct) link, which you can use for streaming.**

.

.

.

**Steps:**

**1 step:** Forward (or send) your message to https://t.me/uploadgrammebot.

**2 step:** Take the responded link.

**3 step:** Add ?raw to that link.

**4 step:** Now, you can use that link to stream(in websites, apps and in telegram itself, etc.)

.

.

.

**Example:**

**1 step:** *I sent random audio from channel to https://t.me/uploadgrammebot.*

**2 step:** *It responded with message:*

> ✅ Your download link was generated. Link:
> https://dl.uploadgram.me/62d82d67b6955h

**3 step:** *I took https://dl.uploadgram.me/62d82d67b6955h, added ?raw: https://dl.uploadgram.me/62d82d67b6955h?raw*

**4 step:** Use it everywhere for stream and download.

Comment: I hope I could help, even tho question is from them 2016 years